# Pegando Evento Collapsing Toolbar Android

Tags: android

Existe alguma forma de identificar o evento de collapsing da CollapsingToolbar?

Tipo um onChangeCollapsingListener

O que preciso fazer é setar a visibilidade de alguns componentes da tela quando a CollapsingToolbar da um expand ou um collapsing.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

O `AppBarLayout` tem um listener para ser notificado de mudanças de `offset`.

Acredito que seja possível ser notificado quando ele está completamente colapsado ou expandido da seguinte maneira:

```
AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener  listener = new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        if(collapsingToolbar.getHeight() + verticalOffset < 2 * ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(collapsingToolbar)) {
            // CollapsingToolbar esta colapsado
        } else {
            // CollapsingToolbar esta expandindo
        }
    }
};

appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(listener);
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595741/show-view-when-toolbar-collapses